# How to programmatically set keyboard shortcut on Mac?

Tags: osx, keyboard, xkb

On OSX Sierra, where can I control my keyboard shortcuts through the file system?

I'd like to script the setup of the equivalent of `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` in `/etc/defaults/keyboard` on ubuntu, but on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I use [one of the Global Hotkeys add-ons](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11688/global-hotkey) for OS X for this. The first, eponymous one, doesn't have a text file to store your configurations in but you can store them in a directory of the shortcuts (aliases) that you want. Each alias is linked to a key by an entry in the Global Hotkeys directories. You can set up a *Terminal* command to be an alias like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window).

Comment: For the _Terminal_ stored command I use the last method in the link above: using the _New Command_ command in the _Terminal_ Shell menu. Note also that you can drop-and-drag anything on your Desktop or in Finder to the _Terminal_ window and it'll turn it into a command-line path to whatever you dragged.